# performBatchUpdates on collectionview & allow user interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to let the user have some control over the screen while updates are being performed on a collection view.

`[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                            [self.collectionView reloadData];
                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];`

I've tried wrapping the whole thing in an animation block and UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction but no dice. Any thoughts how this might be done?

Thanks!

Comment: did you end up figuring this out? running into the same problem now :(

Comment: Still no solution?

Comment: Something? anyone?